# DRY(Don't repeat yourself) Principle and BFFs (Backend-for-Frontend)

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, rest, node.js, dry

We are about to plan our server architecture and we want to use the BFF strategy with node.js servers to serve multiple front-end apps.

However we also want to be able to scale easily (e.g. a new front-end should be served) and want to reuse code with minimal maintenance overhead.

So my questions are:

1. How can I scale and manage a network of BFFs

   - that have similarities but also differences
   - that are written with node.js and follow the REST pattern (but dont make it a requirement)
2. Are there other ways to reuse code for multiple BFFs without the use of packaging (as you will need to maintain many packages this way and development of new features require changes in those packages as well).

My idea was to create some kind of server manager that creates and runs new BFFs based on a configuration and a module. But Im not completely satisfied with that approach because it dynamic enough, generates overhead with the modularization, might become monolithic and because I smell a better solution. I cant be the only one with this kind of problem, can I?

**Edit**

I have added a Picture of the Code Duplication that I see. This is the simplest form, the question is what you are going to do if you have 10 Bffs all using service2.

Now service2 gets a new feature (or any other kind of update) that you have to add to each bff. If the developer is really unlucky, he may have to think about configuring e.g. BFF7 differently for Service2 than the rest.

Also the Problem is not only to connect the BFF to the Services but also to provide to the frontends if it is the same thing.

So on the one hand you have many similarities that should be abstracted, but they should be configurable as well.

Hope that clarifies things.

[image]

**Edit2**

I noticed that I only thought about REST APIs, but maybe a BFF is also supposed to support other stuff as well (socket.io e.g. for a chat)

Comment: What are the differences?

Comment: Well the idea of BFF is usually to have a backend specific to a certain frontend. This way you can easily implement Features that are specific for that frontend. My problem is that a lot of features/use-cases are the same for many BFFs and I consequently dont want to solve a use-case multiple times (Hence DRY). If you need an example: BFF.A provide simple user for a user search. BFF.B provide extended user for a profile. Both make 1 or many request to other backend services. But both will make a request to get the simple  user from some backend service.

Comment: Dont know if that example is perfectly describing the problem, but I hope if goes into the right direction.

Comment: If you guys vote this comment I will try to provide a more detailed example and edit the question.

Comment: Why not find out all the similarities and put them into a Microservice? For example the case you just described would result in a User Domain.

Comment: Is this Service Behind the BFFs? Or should the frontend know that service (then its another architecture)? Also an extra microservice = new project = more maintenance overhead, so it must be worth it. In case its behind the BFFs, you have the same problem as I described, because you need to implement the connections. Isn't there a way to dynamically add endpoints, functionality etc. to BFFs, so that they arent only compatible with the backend but can also automatically provide them to the frontend?

Comment: I think if this question would just focus on either code reuse or scalability, then this with be a good question. As it stands it is too broad.

Comment: Hmmm... I thought that both are important aspects of an architecture. At least for a real life project you might want a solution that respects both. Do you think that if I ask 2 questions for code reuse and scalability, I get answers that I can combine?